# HTMLで表示しているデータ配列の番号をjavascript側で取得したい

Tags: javascript, html

HTML5とSpring Bootで勉強中です。

下記のような形で、画面上にコントロールソース側から渡したtestLabelが複数表示することを確認でき、
islinkがtrueの場合に、画面上リンク可能な表示、押下するとjavascript側で`change()`が呼ばれることを確認できました。

ただ、このリストの何番目が押下されたかをjavascript側でどのように取得したらよいのでしょうか。
また
HTML側の `<a href="#" th:text="${test.testLabel}" onclick="change()"></a>` も
期待した動きにはなっているのですが、通常このような記載はおかしいのでしょうか。
＃onclickのあたりがどうなのだろうと思っています。

■javaコントロールソース側
  下記の情報をもつリストを返しています
  boolean islink
  String testLabel

■HTML側

```
<div th:each="test, stat:${testlist}">
    <div th:if="${test.islink} == false">
        <div th:text="${test.testLabel}"></div>
    </div>
    <div th:if="${test.islink} == true">
        <a href="#" th:text="${test.testLabel}" onclick="change()"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

■javaScript側

```
function changeLanguage() {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

質問にはjsライブラリについて言及がないので、ピュアjsで書きます。
今回の問題を一般的にいうと、「ある要素について、その兄弟要素のなかでの順番を得たい」ということになります。であるならば、兄弟要素のリストをループで検索してしまうのが一番簡単でわかりやすいと思います。
イベントハンドラの設定についてですが、個人的には`onclick`などの属性で設定するよりも、javascriptコードから設定することが、コード分離の観点から推奨されると考えています。またこうした子要素各々について処理を設定する場合、各子要素ではなく、これらを内包するコンテナ（親）要素にイベントハンドラを設定するのがスマートだと思います。
ここでは、コンテナ要素に対してクリック時のイベントハンドラを設定し、子要素がクリックされたら、その要素の順番を取得するところまでをサンプルコードとして示します。

```js
// コンテナ要素にイベントハンドラを設定
var container = document.getElementById('container');
container.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  // クリックされた子要素を特定
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  while (target.parentElement !== container) {
    target = target.parentElement;
  }
  
  // 兄弟要素を検索して順番を取得
  var children = container.children;
  var index = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if (children[i] === target) {
      index = i;
    }
  }
  
  // index === -1のときはエラー
  if (index === -1) {
    console.error(target);
  } else {
    // 処理
    console.log('index = %d', index);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="container" th:each="test, stat:${testlist}">
    <div th:if="${test.islink} == false">
        <div th:text="${test.testLabel}">text index=0</div>
    </div>
    <div th:if="${test.islink} == true">
        <a href="#" th:text="${test.testLabel}">link index=1</a>
    </div>
    <div th:if="${test.islink} == true">
        <a href="#" th:text="${test.testLabel}">link index=2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

不明な点があればお手数ですがコメントをお願いします。

---

追記:

```
// クリックされた子要素を特定
var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
while (target.parentElement !== container) {
  target = target.parentElement;
}
```

この部分について補足します。まず`var target = e.target || e.srcElement;`は、イベントハンドラに渡されるイベントオブジェクトから、実際にクリックイベントが発生したDOM要素を取得しています。`||`で*srcElement*を参照しているのは、互換性を考えて（古いブラウザでは`target`プロパティがなく、代わりに`srcElement`に同じものが入っている）のことですので、場合によっては不要かもしれません。
また、`while()...`の部分ですが、先ほど取得した`target`、つまり実際にクリックイベントが発生した要素というのは、コンテナ要素の直下の要素（つまり子要素）ではなく、さらにその下に位置する孫要素かもしれません。たとえば`<a href="#" th:text="${test.testLabel}">link index=1</a>`とかです。こういう場合は兄弟要素のリストを検索しても該当しないので、親要素をたどっていって、コンテナ要素の子要素、つまり`<div th:if="${test.islink} == true">`までたどり着くという処理になります。説明が下手ですがわからなければまた編集します。

```
<!-- このコンテナ要素にイベントハンドラを設定 -->
<div id="container" th:each="test, stat:${testlist}">
    <!-- これが子要素 -->
    <div th:if="${test.islink} == false">
        <!-- クリックイベントはこの要素（孫要素）で発生するかもしれない -->
        <!-- これをcontainer.childrenのなかから検索してもみつからない -->
        <div th:text="${test.testLabel}">text index=0</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！

addEventListenerでquerySelector()で指定した要素のクリックイベントを登録しているのだろうと思うのですが
querySelector()の使い方がいまいちわかりません。
body内のdiv定義している要素全てということなのでしょうか。

Comment: HTML部分を
<div class="tesclasst" id="test">
でくくり、以下のようにすることで、
var container = document.querySelector('body > div.test');
var children = container.children;では、testlist分の要素を取得できていることを確認できました。

Comment: ただよくわからないのが、以下で、
  // クリックされた子要素を特定e.target || e.srcElementで何を取得しているのかがよくわかりませんでした。
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  while (target.parentElement !== container) {
    target = target.parentElement;
  }

Comment: `querySelector`で余計な混乱を生じさせてしまったかもしれません。要はコンテナ要素を取得できればよいので、適当にidを振って取得するように書き換えました。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。まだ理解しておらず、もう少し熟読させてください。

Answer (score 0):

### jQueryの例

欲しいインデックスは、
「クリックされた要素の親要素が、（その親要素の）親要素の何番目に出現するか」
です。

#### クリックされた要素の取得

`onclick`属性内のコードでは、クリックイベントを`event`という変数で参照出来ます。
ですので、ここで`change`関数を呼ぶ際に`event`を引数で渡します。

```
onclick="change(event)"
```

change関数ではこれを`ev`という名前で受ける事とします。

```
function change(ev){
```

クリックイベントには`target`というプロパティがあり、これがクリックされた要素です。
change関数内では`ev.target`として参照出来る事になります。
jQueryの要素オブジェクトにするには`$`に渡せばよいです。

```
$(ev.target)
```

#### 親要素の取得

jQueryでは`parent()`メソッドが使えます。

```
$(ev.target).parent()
```

#### インデックスの取得

jQueryでは`index()`メソッドが使えます。

```
$(ev.target).parent().index()
```

```js
function change(ev){
 var index = $(ev.target).parent().index();
 $("#show_index").text(index);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
 <div>
  <div>Test Label 00</div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <a href="#" onclick="change(event)">Test Label 01</a>
 </div>
 <div>
  <div>Test Label 02</div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <a href="#" onclick="change(event)">Test Label 03</a>
 </div>
 <div>
  <a href="#" onclick="change(event)">Test Label 04</a>
 </div>
</div>

<p>インデックス: <span id="show_index"></span></p>
```

---

以下、本題とずれます。

### サーバ側の見直し

#### ネストを浅くする

ネストが深いと苦労します。
表示したい要素を`<div th:if...>` でくるまずに、表示したい要素のタグ自体に`th:if`を設定すれば、ネストが一つ減って`parent()`がいらなくなるのではないでしょうか。

#### インデックスをサーバ側で生成しておく

おそらく、サーバサイドのコード、データ構造、DOM、JavaScriptが密結合になりすぎています。
DOM構造とデータ構造を一致させるというのも一つの方法ですが、質問から察するにもう限界ではないでしょうか。

例えばThymeleaf(これを使っているのですよね？)には

> index プロパティ: 0始まりの現在の「繰り返しインデックス」
>   [繰り返しステータスの保持](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf_ja.html#%E7%B9%B0%E3%82%8A%E8%BF%94%E3%81%97%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E4%BF%9D%E6%8C%81)

このような物がありますから、`onClick`での`change`関数呼び出し時にインデックスを引数で渡すようなHTMLを生成してしまえば、JavaScript側では何も考えなくてよいです。

```
onclick="change(1)"
```

DOM構造が変更されてもJavaScritの変更は必要なくなります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。上記にてカウントを渡すことは可能であることがわかりました。